# Yocto project cannot find asm/errno.h

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, yocto, openembedded

I'm trying to compile a program that requires `asm/errno.h` header.

```
Building C object CMakeFiles/modem.dir/src/client.c.o
| /home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -Dmodem_EXPORTS -std=gnu99  -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon  --sysroot=/home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/mdm9607  -O2 -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I/home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/libmodem/1.0-r0/libmodem/src -I/home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/libmodem/1.0-r0/libmodem/include    -o CMakeFiles/modem.dir/src/client.c.o   -c /home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/libmodem/1.0-r0/libmodem/src/client.c
| [ 83%] /home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/libmodem/1.0-r0/libmodem/src/client.c:14:25: fatal error: asm/ernno.h: No such file or directory
|  #include <asm/ernno.h>
                         ^
```

The `--sysroot` argument is set correctly to my targets sysroot, but gcc still can't find the header, even though it's clearly there:

```
ls -la /home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/tmp-glibc/sysroots/mdm9607/usr/include/asm/ | grep "errno\.h"
-rw-r--r--  3 kristupas kristupas    31 Kov  9 16:06 errno.h
```

Doing

```
echo | /home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc -R -Wp. -v -
```

returns this:

```
--includedir=/home/kristupas/yocto/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include
```

This is the include directory for the host, which does not contain `asm/errno.h`. Shouldn't it point to targets sysroot instead?

Comment: Personally, I've never understood why anybody prefers CMale to "make"...

Comment: @paulsm4 it ties in nicely with the open embedded toolchain. I don't have to write a separate installation task inside the bitbake recipe. Also things like dependency management ease the development a lot.

Comment: ernno.h vs errno.h -- the typo might explain the issues you are seeing?

Comment: Good catch, jku :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I misspelled `errno` and failed to notice it for hours!